# Cannot run the same App that used to run fine

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, winjs, visual-studio-2015

I am creating universal Windows App using Visual Studio 2015. The App initially run fine but then something happen and App failed to been deployed. I just get following error.

[image]

I have tried uninstall the App, cleaning the bin and bld directories (even removing these), changing the package name (guid and display name) but nothing works. Any ideas on what cause this error and how to resolve it?

EDIT
Events Viewer is showing following entry.

> ActivateApplicationForContractByAppIdAsUserWithHost of the app
>   0c2164b1-2ddd-4cef-9305-f061db235a23_nef0eajndckej!App for the
>   Windows.Launch contract failed with Install failed. Please contact
>   your software vendor..

Comment: did you install it while logged in as a different user on the same machine, possibly from the store? i seem to recall seeing this and had to uninstall from the other user before i could launch again from VS using my main account.  still thinking about this more...

Comment: Not that I can remember. I do have more than one users on this particular machine.